# Declare function before each unit test with testthat package

Tags: r, testthat

I want to create global functions which be used in each unit test of my package:

- `beforeTest()` which creates database table to test
- `afterTest()` which drops the test database table.

Files:

/tests/testthat.R:

```
library(mypackage)  
library(testthat)

beforeTest <- function() {
  # implementation
}

afterTest <- function() {
  # implementation
}

test_check("mypackage")
```

/tests/testthat/unit_test_1.R:

```
test_that("mytest", {
  beforeTest()
  on.exit(afterTest()) 

  # implemetation of the unit test...
  # ...
  # ...
})
```

The problem is that file `unit_test_1.R` doesn't see the functions `beforeTest()` and `afterTest()`

Comment: I guess it depends on how you execute your tests (RStudio, devtools...). I would put the functions into a separate R file in tests/testthat and source the functions in each test file. That is how I "inject" db connections in my packages...

Comment: I execute the tests by `devtools::test()` Thx I will do the same.